# PHP SoftLayer_User_Customer (createOjbect)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Creating user with PHP SoftLayer_User_Customer (createOjbect). The username assigned is in the format of "AcctNum_UserEmail" regardless of the username requested. It appears to be the only username returned by the API. Can I get confirmation re: this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yep that is the expected behavior, this is because now your softlayer user is linked automatically to IBMid and you will have the option to use Bluemix-based IBM platform services and applications.

Regards